# Python - Pygame window not popping up

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm currently making a game using Pygame library and my problem is that the window isn't opening up. The code is running in Visual Studio 2022, but upon running the project, it doesn't seem to be running as intended, as it immediately stops. I've searched a few other questions on Stack Overflow but all of them tell to make an event loop, which I have already created.

Code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

class RockPaperScissors:
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        
        pygame.display.update()
        
        self.game_loop()
                
    def game_loop(self):
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                
            self.screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
            
            pygame.display.flip()
            self.clock.tick(60)
        
if __name__ == "_main__":
    rps = RockPaperScissors()
```

At first I had no event loop, which is when I first tried finding an answer, which was to implement the loop. However, after following several solutions and compiling many times, the problem persisted. Please help!

Comment: `"__main__"`! Not  `"_main__"`

Comment: Oh yes sorry! Stupid mistake on my part lol.